# How to log out of Ubuntu One application, log into different account?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I accidentally created two Ubuntu One accounts on two different computers.  However, I cannot log out of either account on the Ubuntu One application, so I'm stuck with two different (non-syncing!) accounts.

I have deleted one account, and now when I start up Ubuntu One on that computer it says:

```
File Sync error. (auth failed (AUTH_FAILED))
```

The information could not be retrieved. Maybe your internet connection is down?"

How can I reconfigure the Ubuntu One application on that computer to the right account?  Any help is greatly appreciated!  :)

Comment: Do not put SOLVED in the title (I removed it), instead mark as accepted the best answer you get.

Answer (score 5):

On the computer set up with the account you don't want to keep, follow steps 1-3 in the "Removing Ubuntu One Client" section of this FAQ:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/HowDoICompletelyRemoveAndReinstallUbuntuOne

(it should not be necessary to remove and reinstall the actual client software).

From this point you should have a clean slate and can set up the client again using the other account.

Comment: Just follow what James Henstridge said and you should be just fine :) Best answer I've seen in a while...

Comment: Mark @James' answer as the correct answer.  Unlike the ubuntuforums.org site, you need to mark things here as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Well I just started working on Ubuntu just couple of days back. But I able to figure this out that by the functionality of "Remove Device" from Ubuntu One [On-line account](https://one.ubuntu.com/account/) we can remove the Ubuntu One login in desktop cloud.!

[image]

I just tried it and it worked.